# return value to app.js file in node js

Tags: node.js, express, export

I have two files, one called filename and the second called app.js, both files are on the server side. From filename.js filder I am returing a value string from ensureAuthentication method to app.js file, so i export the function:

```
function ensureAuthentication(){
  return 'tesstestest';
}
exports.ensureAuthentication = ensureAuthentication;
```

in app.js file i do following

```
var appjs = require('filename');
console.log(appjs.ensureAuthentication);
```

result is always is undifined in console??! why is that any idea?

Comment: where is login variable declared? should'nt it be appjs.ensureAuthentication?

Comment: see edit @SohaibFarooqi

Comment: use it like `appjs.ensureAuthentication()`

Comment: thats what i get  when i do it TypeError: appjs.ensureAuthentication is not a function

Comment: the only problem with your code is require('filename') this means you are requiring some node_module so try to replace it require('./filename')

Answer (score 0):

You should try this in your app.js -

```
var login = require('filename');
console.log(login());
```

or you can use this :

```
var login = require('filename')();
console.log(login);
```

**Explanation:** Whenever you are exporting a function using exports you need to execute it to get the return value from it.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems with your code:

1. You need to require with a relative path (**notice the ./**):

   var appjs = require('./filename');
2. To get the string value you need to invoke ensureAuthentication as a function:

   console.log(appjs.ensureAuthentication());

---

**UPDATE**

This update addresses the [screenshot posted in the comments](https://i.imgsafe.org/81e1f17fb7.png).

In the screenshot you pasted in the comments, you have the following line:

```
module.exports = router
```

That assigns a *different exports object* to the module. So your local reference to `exports` is no longer the same object.

Change that line to

```
module.exports = exports = router
```

Which will preserve the reference to `exports` which you use next.

Comment: i get error when i do so appjs.ensureAuthentication is not a function

Comment: Are you sure the code is still the same as described above in filename where you are exporting `exports.ensureAuthentication = ensureAuthentication`?

Comment: 100 % sure :( @xianwill

Comment: Seems like the code you show above isn't what you're running because this works when I run it. -- filename.js and app.js are in the same directory, contents of filename.js are exactly as you described above, I have made the two edits I described above in app.js.

Comment: i promise u its exactly the same :(

Comment: This answer looks correct to me. `require('./filename');` and `console.log(appjs.ensureAuthentication());` should work so long as the files are in the same directory.

Comment: In your code you should also do `function ensureAuthentication()` notice the brackets which are missing in yours.

Comment: Updated the answer - I noticed in your screenshot you are overwriting the exports object before you add your function to it.

Comment: Check my answer for a complete solution Kob_24

Comment: Also - @RichardMacarthy is correct that you need parens in your function declaration - though those are present in the screenshot, and you would have had a syntax error instead of a undefined or a  runtime error if they were not already present in your code.

Comment: @Kob_24 take a look at this post regarding module.exports and exports - http://www.hacksparrow.com/node-js-exports-vs-module-exports.html. Like I described in the answer, your code is assigning `module.exports` to a different object so your ensureAuthentication function isn't being exported.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var appjs = require('filename');
console.log(appjs.ensureAuthentication());
```

note the () after the function call. This will execute your function. The console.log() call will then print the returned value.

Comment: as i said this will through following error : TypeError: appjs.ensureAuthentication is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Try this, make sure both files are in the same directory.  You have a few errors with your code.  Missing brackets, and not importing correctly in app.js.

**filename.js**

`function ensureAuthentication(){ // You are missing the brackets here.
  return 'tesstestest';
}
exports.ensureAuthentication = ensureAuthentication;`

**app.js**

`var appjs = require('./filename'); // You are missing the ./ here.
console.log(appjs.ensureAuthentication()); // Logs 'tesstestest'`

Comment: brackers where there. i just missed it when i typed the question. ur solution is the same what i have on my machine now, and its not working and still dont understand why!

Comment: running > `node app.js` logs to the console for me.  How are you running this?

Comment: yes and i do i use nodemon and this is the output Fri May 27 2016 12:30:13 GMT+0200 (CEST) : ------- _ :

Comment: Try this `exports.router = router;` and `exports.ensureAuthentication = ensureAuthentication;`  You will have to change where router is imported to get this to work elsewhere.  I think the `module.exports` line is causing you problems.

Comment: i think so also, lets give it a try

Comment: yeb, still the same problem

Answer (score -1):

Here you go with the working code

**filename.js**

```
function ensureAuthentication(){
  return 'tesstestest';
}

module.exports = {
    ensureAuthentication : ensureAuthentication
}
```

**app.js**

```
var appjs = require('./utils/sample');

console.log(appjs.ensureAuthentication());
```